# New version replacing old changes in git

Tags: php, git, gitlab

I am currently facing issue in the following process. Any help would be appreciated.

- Initial Master Branch Version: v1.0
- In the Development Branch (v1.1), I removed one file from the Project and the changes has been moved to Master branch
- Another Developer who has been working on v1.0 is unaware of these changes (file removal). This developer has submitted a merge request
- If I try to merge the new changes, the changes from v1.1 has been replaced (i.e. the deleted field is again available on the project)

Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Can you provide the commit tree? Or at least the commands you’ve used with their outputs?

Comment: I would say that your error was merging to Master